# scripts and css not loading in web server

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter

My project build on **CodeIgniter** is working fine in `localhost` but running it in *webhost*. Its not able to find the scripts and stylesheet and thus the site is running but without any design appearing. 
I made the following changes before running it in webhost:

**config.php:**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/scholarship/';
```

The project is inside *scholarship directory* inside some domain name

**database.php:**
*All the database settings are properly done and is working fine database part no error*

Comment: could you post a directory-tree and the link-tag for the css?

Comment: Go the the 'rendered' HTML code from the browser and check if the URL that is being rendered for the css files is actually existing.

Comment: make sure your css and scripts are located out side of the application folder. Need more information though.

Comment: can you pls send your website link. : Check file permissions and mod_rewite module is enable.  ----> If file permission is ok and mod_rewrite is enable then write your website link instead of $_server eg  http://www abc com/scholarship/

Comment: here is the website link http://www.janamukhicooperative.com/scholarship/ PLEASE click on "click to visit" link .

Answer (score 0):

check your htaccess to make sure it is correct
on chrome, right click - view sourse - find and click the url of the script